# What do you call an integer number with increasing digits from left to right?

Tags: number-theory, terminology, integers

This is my first question in this community, it might be obvious but I haven't found a good answer after searching on Google and Mathematics StackExchange.

**What do you call an integer number whose digits are strictly increasing in value from left to right?**

E.g.: 1234, 345, 6789, etc...

Based on [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1667421/stairstep-numbers), some people seem to call it a stairstep number, but is there an "official" name for these numbers?
I'm looking for something similar to [Perfect numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number), [Amicable numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amicable_numbers), etc.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think such numbers are mathematically interesting enough to have warranted a standard name. They're usually just described by the property they have, as you did. on [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A009993), for example, they're called "numbers whose decimal digits are in strictly increasing order".

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. I guess they're not that special, but I think many people find them oddly satisfying, and was surprised that I didn't find a Wikipedia article about them. But now that I think about it, they aren't that interesting at all :D

Comment: ...just "numbers"?